# Calculate an average value for the bar chart using the most frequent value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

If I plot the values of "Price" data (with Python) using bar chart with bins, I get this result:

[image]

So, the price is between 0 and 15. Let's imagine that these is the distribution of the values of price for some particular hour of the day.

In Kibana I want to create a line plot that will calculate an average price per hours. If I apply `Average Bucket` or `Average`, then basically the mean value is calculated from the data. However, in my case the "average" is basically the most frequent value from the histogram.

For example, in the above-given chart the average value would be `1.1` because it has more than `800` entries.

How can I calculate this kind of "average" in Kibana?

Comment: You need Pipeline Avg Bucket aggregation I guess. For e.g., If my avg per hour distribution is 3,4,5,4,5,2 so the avg bucket aggregation would be (3+4+5+4+5+2)/6 = 3.833. You need this 3.833, right?

Comment: @HatimStovewala: No, I need the most frequent value, and I call this frequent value as "Average". So, I don't want to calculate Average in the classical way, because for my application it does not make sense. In your sample data, the answer would be between 4 an 5, e.g. (4+5)/2 = 4.5

Comment: Why not just use the *histogram* aggregation over *price*?

Comment: @YuWatanabe: Ok, thanks. In this case, the parameter `Interval` in Kibana should be equal to `0.2` in order to properly reflect my example? Should I use `Average Bucket`?

Comment: @YuWatanabe: Should I use `Average Bucket` with `Max` aggregation? I guess that since I want to get the bin with the maximum number of entries, I should use `Max` inside `Average Bucket`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets straighten out your goal. Your goal is to ,

*Find the most occurred price with in each hour.*

This is too *high level* to implement this on kibana, lets make it more in elasticsearch context.

1. Set the x-axis to date time with hourly interval
2. Find the most occurred price with in each hourly bucket

This can be don by below setting.

#### y-Axis

Set to *Metric Aggregations - Average*

#### x-Axis

Set to *Date Histogram* with

1. Field : YOUR TIMESTAMP
2. Interval : hourly

Below is the important part for your case.

#### Split Series

Set to *Terms*

1. Field : price
2. Order By : Custom Metric (count)
3. Order : Descending
4. Size :1

   "aggs": {
       "2": {
         "date_histogram": {
           "field": "@timestamp",
           "interval": "1h",
           "time_zone": "Asia/Tokyo",
           "min_doc_count": 1
         },
         "aggs": {
           "3": {
             "terms": {
               "field": "price",
               "size": 1,
               "order": {
                 "_count": "desc"
               }
             },
             "aggs": {
               "1": {
                 "avg": {
                   "field": "price"
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }

If you look at the query in kibana, you could see that the 2nd term aggregation is just returning the highest count document.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Average Bucket" -> Aggregation "Max" for the Y axis?

Comment: If you just want the *max* price within the histogram bucket. Then answer is *yes* . I just assumed your thought.

Comment: I want just to get one number per hour. In the X axis I have hours. The histogram that I showed in my question is the price distribution for some particular hour, for example, between 15:00 and 16:00. So, in the Y axis I want to get the most frequent price for each hour. Therefore, I assume that in the X axis I should group by "Hour", while in the Y axis I should use "Average Bucket"->"Histogram"->"Price"  and then Aggregations "Max"->"Price". As I understood from your answer, this is what will give you what I need.

Comment: I see. All you need to do is set **Aggregation** of *x-axis*  as *date histogram (interval hour)*  and set the **Metric Aggregations**  of *y-axis* to *Max* . Then you will get the maximum price within each hour.

Comment: It should not be the maximum price. It should be the most frequent price. So, I should select the most frequent bin for each Hour.

Comment: Just imagine that for each Hour I have a distribution of Price. So, for each hour I want to select the most frequent price according to the corresponding distribution (related to this Hour).

Comment: You mean the *latest* ? Latest is the data that comes at the top when data is sorted chronologically in descending order.  Then set  **y-axis** to  *Average* for price. And **x-axis** to *date histogram* , add **Split Series**  to *Term*  and aggregate with your timestamp. Order should be *descending* and just return 1 document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156635/discussion-between-yu-watanabe-and-dinosaurius).